# Conditional field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, conditional

I'm trying to code a conditional sentence in QGIS to calculate a vector field.

I have 5 variables. I'd like to calculate the simple average if all variables are >= 3.
If all variables are not >=3, the result should be the lowest value of all of them.

Comment: My big problem is define the part of the conditional of "the result should be the lowest value of all of them."

Comment: Maybe something like: `if("field_1"+"field_2"+"field_3"+"field_4"+"field_5" >=3, ("field_1"+"field_2"+"field_3"+"field_4"+"field_5")/5, min("field_1","field_2","field_3","field_4","field_5"))`

Comment: If the values should not be added like Joseph wrote but checked if all variables are above 3 you need to exchange the "+" with "and" in the first part.